# Google style pagination

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to implement google stlye pagination that will allow me to select page 1, 2, 3 and so on. Currently I have functionality that will bring me to the next page and previous page. As you can see the api will return 5 hotels per page. I'm new to angular and node so I'm not quite sure how to do this. Any help would be great.

You can see below my .ts file and .html file.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WebService } from './web.service';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Component({
selector: 'hotels',
templateUrl: './hotels.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./hotels.component.css']
})
export class HotelsComponent {

constructor(private webService: WebService, private authService: AuthService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        if (sessionStorage.start) {
            this.start = sessionStorage.start;
            } 
        this.webService.getHotels(this.start);
        }

        nextPage() {
            this.start = Number(this.start) + 5;
            sessionStorage.start = Number(this.start);
            this.webService.getHotels(this.start);
           }
           previousPage() {
            if (this.start > 0) {
            this.start = Number(this.start) - 5;
            sessionStorage.start = Number(this.start);
            this.webService.getHotels(this.start);
            }
           }

hotel_list;    
start = 0;



}
```

---

```
<div class="container"  style="margin-top:100px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div *ngFor="let hotel of webService.hotel_list | async">
                <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3" 
[routerLink]="['/hotels', hotel._id]" style="cursor: pointer">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        {{ hotel.Name }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        This hotel is based in
                        {{ hotel.Location }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        {{ hotel.review_count }}
                        reviews available
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- col -->
    </div> <!-- row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <button (click)="previousPage()">Previous</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
            <button (click)="nextPage()">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div> <!-- container -->
```

Web Service

```
import { Http, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class WebService {

hotelID;

private hotels_private_list = [];
private hotelsSubject = new Subject();
hotel_list = this.hotelsSubject.asObservable();

private hotel_private_list = [];
private hotelSubject = new Subject();
hotel = this.hotelSubject.asObservable();

private reviews_private_list = [];
private reviewsSubject = new Subject();
reviews = this.reviewsSubject.asObservable();

url: string = 'http://localhost:3000/api/hotels/';
hotelsArray = [];

constructor(private http: Http) { 


}

getHotels(start) {
    return this.http.get(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/hotels?start=' + start)
        .subscribe(response => {
            this.hotels_private_list = response.json();
            this.hotelsSubject.next(this.hotels_private_list);
        })
}



getHotel(id: string) {
    return this.http.get(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/hotels/' + id)
        .subscribe(response => {
            this.hotel_private_list = [];
            this.hotel_private_list.push(response.json());
            this.hotelSubject.next(this.hotel_private_list);
            this.hotelID = id;
        })
}

getReviews(id) {
    this.http.get(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/hotels/' + id + '/reviews')
        .subscribe(
            response => {
                this.reviews_private_list = response.json();
                this.reviewsSubject.next(
                    this.reviews_private_list);

            }
        )
}

postReview(review) {
    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('username', review.name);
    urlSearchParams.append('text', review.review);
    urlSearchParams.append('stars', review.stars);

    this.http.post(
    "http://localhost:3000/api/hotels/" +
    review.hotelID + "/reviews",
    urlSearchParams)
    .subscribe(
    response => {
    this.getReviews(review.hotelID);
    }
    )
}
```

}

Comment: It's not clear how your webservice is returning the data. Also, what isn't working, exactly?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I have added in my WebService for reference. Basically I'm asking for help on how to implement a pagination scheme like google that you can choose page 1, page 2, page 3 etc

Comment: It doesn't look like you're doing anything with your web service return. You're invoking, it but not doing anything with the response. Here is a very basic example of using Pagination with a Table. https://stackblitz.com/angular/dnbnngyodavg?file=app%2Ftable-pagination-example.ts

Comment: I would also recommend not using global variables. Define your component level variables as members/properties. ie: `public hotelsArray: any[];`

Answer (score 3):

Create a reusable pagination component as follow.

```
import {
Component,
Input,
Output,
EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';
import { OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'pagination',
templateUrl: './pagination.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./pagination.component.css']
})
export class PaginationComponent implements OnChanges {
@Input('total-items') totalItems;
@Input('page-size') pageSize;
@Output('page-changed') pageChanged = new EventEmitter();
pages: any[];
currentPage = 1;
page: number;

ngOnChanges() {
    this.currentPage = 1;

    var pagesCount = Math.ceil(this.totalItems / this.pageSize);
    this.pages = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= pagesCount; i++)
        this.pages.push(i);
}

changePage(page) {
    this.currentPage = page;
    this.pageChanged.emit(page);
}

previous() {
    if (this.currentPage == 1)
        return;

    this.currentPage--;
    this.pageChanged.emit(this.currentPage);
}

next() {
    if (this.currentPage == this.pages.length)
        return;

    this.currentPage++;
    this.pageChanged.emit(this.currentPage);
}
}
```

And below is the view for the component

```
<nav *ngIf="totalItems > pageSize">
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
    <li [class.disabled]="currentPage == 1">
        <a class="pagetag" (click)="previous()" aria-label="Previous">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li [class.active]="currentPage == page" *ngFor="let page of pages" (click)="changePage(page)">
        <a class="pagetag" *ngIf="page < currentPage+5 && page > currentPage-5">{{ page }}</a>
    </li>
    <li [class.disabled]="currentPage == pages.length">
        <a class="pagetag" (click)="next()" aria-label="Next">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

And you can use it from your page like this. 
In the component you want to use the pagination, pass the page number to your service. Note that your API should be able to accept a page number and accordingly return the data:

```
 private getDataFromServise(pageNumber) {
    this.webService.getHotels(pageNumber)
        .subscribe(result => { this.result = result});
 }

 onPageChange(page) {
    this.getDataFromServise(page);
}

 <div class="text-center">
    <pagination [total-items]="total-item-count" [page-size]="PAGE_SIZE" (page- 
    changed)="onPageChange($event)"></pagination>
</div>
```

You can find the code for pagination component on my github page.
[pagination](https://github.com/ImanMe/JobBoard.v1/tree/master/JobBoard.Admin/ClientApp/app/pagination)
I have been using this pagination-component in few projects and it serves the purpose. I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi thanks!  I want  the pagination in my hotel component, just struggling where to put the last part of the code you showed. Would you be able to reference it in my hotel.components.ts?

Comment: The last part goes to hotel component. @Watsyyy

Comment: When I put that into the hotel.component.ts , this.result gets error: Property 'result' does not exist on type 'HotelsComponent'. and same error for page number

Comment: Define variable result of type any in your hotel class. I got rid of pageNumber in the code.

Comment: Hi no errors now, can only see previous and next button in web browser. I put this in the bottom of my hotels.component.html                                                                  
                       <div class="text-center">
    <pagination [total-items]="total-item-count" [page-size]="PAGE_SIZE" (page- 
    changed)="onPageChange($event)"></pagination>
</div>                                                                                        
  Do I need to do anything else to bring up the page 1 | 2 | 3 | ?

Comment: you need to set a number value for total-item-count and page_size.  total-item-count should come from server.

Comment: OK I have got that now, its displaying the page numbers, although when I click on them nothing is returned. What would cause this? Sorry  for all the questions!

Comment: The changePage() method in your component should call your  this.webService.getHotels(); method.  this method should also accept a parameter for page-number, something like this  this.webService.getHotels(pageNumber);